# Read from initial stdin in Go?

Tags: go

I would like to read from the original `stdin` of a Go program. For example, if I did `echo test stdin | go run test.go`, I would want to have access to "test stdin". I've tried reading from `os.Stdin`, but if there's nothing in it, then it will wait for input. I also tried checking the size first, but the `os.Stdin.Stat().Size()` is 0 even when input is passed in.

What can I do?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751429/getting-standard-input-in-golang didn't help?

Comment: Something like "s = System.in.readline()" in java or "$s = <STDIN>" in perl, something simple to do something simple???

Comment: @mowwalker I this question of yours answered? Is something unclear? If not it would be nice of you to mark one of the answers as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, Perl has easy ways to read from file. Cute, cute language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think your question per se has no sensible answer because there's just no such thing as "initial stdin".  Unix-like OSs, and Windows implement the concept of ["standard streams"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin), which works like this (simplified): when a process is created, it automagically has three file descriptors (handles in Windows) open — stdin, stdout and stderr.  No doubts, you're familiar with this concept, but I'd like to stress the meaning of the word "stream" there — in your example, when you call

```
$ echo 'test stdin' | ./stdin
```

the shell creates a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), spawns two processes (one for `echo` and one for your binary) and makes use of the pipe it created: the pipe's write FD is attached to the `echo`'s stdout and the pipe's read FD is attached to your binary's stdin.  Then whatever the `echo` process pleases to write to its stdout is piped (sic!) to the stdin of your process.
(In reality most today's shells implement `echo` as a built-in primitive but this does not in any way change the semantics; your could as well have tried `/bin/echo` instead, which is a real program.  Also note that I just used `./stdin` to refer to your program — this is for clarity, as `go run stdin.go` would do exactly this, in the end.)

Note several crucial things here:

- The writing process (`echo` in your case) is not oblidged to write anything to its stdout (for instance, `echo -n` would not write anything to its stdout and exit successfully).
- It's also able to make arbitrary delays writing its data (either because it wants to make such delays or because it has been preempted by the OS or sleeps in some syscall waiting on some busy system resource etc).
- The [OS buffers transfers over pipes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/43156), and often the code in the program does this, too—though [it may not be apparent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64877396/720999) for an inexperienced programmer. This means what the writing process sends to a pipe, might come out in arbitrary chunks on the reading side.<sup>1</sup>
- There are only two ways to know the writing side has no more data to send over the pipe:

  - Somehow encode this in the data itself (this means using an agreed upon data transfer protocol between the writer and the reader).
  - The writer might close its side of the pipe which would result in the "end of file" condition on the reader side (but only after the buffer is drained and one another call to `read` is attempted, which fails).

Let's wrap this up: the behaviour you're observing is correct and normal.  If you expect to get any data from stdin, you must not expect it to be readily available.  If you also don't want to block on stdin, then create a goroutine which would do blocking reads from stdin in an endless loop (but checking for the EOF condition) and pass collected data up over a channel (possibly after certain processing, if needed).

<sup>1</sup> This is why certain tools which usually occur between two pipes in a pipeline, such as `grep`, might have special options to make them flush their stdout after writing each line — read about the `--line-buffered` option in the [`grep` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for one example.  People who are not aware of this "full buffering by default" semantics are puzzled why `tail -f /path/to/some/file.log | grep whatever | sed ...` seems to stall and not display anything when it's obvious the monitored file gets updated.

---

As a side note: if you were to run your binary "as is", like in

```
$ ./stdin
```

that would not meant the spawned process would not have stdin (or "initial stdin" or whaveter), instead, its stdin would be connected to the same stream your shell receives your keyboard input from (so you could directly type something to your process's stdin).

The only sure way to have a process's stdin connected to nowhere is to use

```
$ ./stdin </dev/null
```

on Unix-like OSes and

```
C:\> stdin <NUL
```

on Windows.  This ["null device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) makes the process see EOF on the first `read` from its stdin.

Comment: `echo -n` does write to stdout, it only omits the newline. Also, the behavior is not normal. For these amounts of data (11 byte) there should be no delay by preemption or something similar.

Comment: @nemo, it doesn't if `-n` is the sole argument. That's what I wanted to actually demonstrate. As to amount of data, preemption might occur everywhere anytime: I could just send `SIGSTOP` to `echo` before it manages to write to the pipe, for instance.  The only guagantee that pipes seem to provide in this respect, is that those 11 bytes will arrive to the pipe in one piece (will not be interleaved), at least that's what I gather from [man pipe(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

Comment: Of course there *could* be happen anything. But I don't think the OP is deliberately killing the test echo just before it writes to the pipe :) It's just not normal behavior and it's very likely the OP did just something wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I asked on IRC, and got a similar response - that there's no difference between the input initially passed with pipe, or with called the program and then typing input.

Answer (score 79):

Reading from stdin using `os.Stdin` should work as expected:

```
package main

import "os"
import "log"
import "io"

func main() {
    bytes, err := io.ReadAll(os.Stdin)

    log.Println(err, string(bytes))
}
```

Executing `echo test stdin | go run stdin.go` should print 'test stdin' just fine.

It would help if you'd attach the code you used to identify the problem you encountered.

For line based reading you can use `bufio.Scanner`:

```
import "os"
import "log"
import "bufio"

func main() {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for s.Scan() {
        log.Println("line", s.Text())
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please suggest a version that can stream from stdin line by line, rather than reading all of the data into memory at once?

Comment: I added a solution for line based reading using `bufio.Reader`.

Comment: What if there's nothing in `os.Stdin`?

Answer (score 6):

You can't check stdin for content, but you can check if stdin is associated with a terminal or a pipe. IsTerminal just takes the standard unix fd numbers (0,1,2). The syscall package has variables assigned so you can do syscall.Stdin if you prefer naming them.

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if ! terminal.IsTerminal(0) {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print(string(b))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no piped data")
    }
}
```