# fmt.Scanln expected newline error

Tags: input, go

I'm trying to learn Go, but stuck with this one: http://ideone.com/hbCamr or http://ideone.com/OvRw7t

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
  var i int
  var f float64
  var s string

  _, err := fmt.Scan(&i)
  if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("read 1 integer: ",i)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
  }

  _, err = fmt.Scan(&f)
  if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("read 1 float64: ",f)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
  }
  _, err = fmt.Scan(&s)
  if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("read 1 string: ",s)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
  }

  _, err = fmt.Scanln(&s)
  if err == nil {
    fmt.Println("read 1 line: ",s)
  } else {
    fmt.Println("Error: ",err)
  }
}
```

for this input:

```
123
123.456
everybody loves ice cream
```

the output was:

```
read 1 integer:  123
read 1 float64:  123.456
read 1 string:  everybody
Error:  Scan: expected newline
```

is this the expected behavior? why doesn't it work like C++ getline? http://ideone.com/Wx8z5o

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is in the [documentation of `Scanln`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln):

> Scanln is similar to Scan, but stops scanning at a newline and after the final item there must be a newline or EOF.

`Scan` behaves as [documented](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) as well:

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments. Newlines count as space. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is less than the number of arguments, err will report why.

To conclude: `Scan` puts each word (a string separated by space) into a corresponding argument, treating newlines as space. `Scanln` does the same but treats newlines as a stop character, not parsing any further after that.

In case you want to read a line (`\n` at the end) use `bufio.Reader` and its [`ReadString`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) method:

```
line, err := buffer.ReadString('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can implement your own `fmt.Scanner`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type newline struct { tok string }

func (n *newline) Scan(state fmt.ScanState, verb rune) error {
   tok, err := state.Token(false, func(r rune) bool {
      return r != '\n'
   })
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   if _, _, err := state.ReadRune(); err != nil {
      if len(tok) == 0 {
         panic(err)
      }
   }
   n.tok = string(tok)
   return nil
}

func main() {
   var n newline
   fmt.Scan(&n)
   fmt.Println(n.tok)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Scanner