# Scan strings containing white spaces using fmt.Scan()/fmt.Scanf()/fmt.Scanln()?

Tags: go, stdin

Using the Go language, to read input strings with spaces, I have to use

```
s, err := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
```

Is there is any way to use `fmt.Scan`, `fmt.Scanf`, or `fmt.Scanln()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fmt.Scanln expected newline error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005899/fmt-scanln-expected-newline-error)

Answer (score -1):

If you're building a CLI tool I highly suggest you check out [cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra). It's written in pure go ([see dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra?tab=imports)) and used by multiple well-known projects.

Alternatively, I wrote a quick (gross) example to demonstrate how you could gain finer control with the `Reader` interface by linearly reading individual bytes from stdin.

```golang
func byteByByte() [][]byte {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    buffer, result := []byte{}, [][]byte{}
    for {
        c, err := reader.ReadByte()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        if c == byte(32) {
            result, buffer = append(result, buffer), []byte{}
            continue
        }
        buffer = append(buffer, c)
    }
    return result
}
```

Here we are temporarily buffering results until a space is reached, at which, the temporary buffer is dumped into a larger one.

This is meant as an example to show you how the reader interface can be used with more control/granularity, not as a piece of code to be used verbatim.

Comment: this will hang if stdin is never closed. this will blow memory if a very large chunk of data is sent to stdin. Why not recommend the regular bufio.Scanner ?