# Setting Values in Go Application at Runtime

Tags: go

I'm writing a go application that writes values to a file.

However, I want the location of that file to be determined at runtime (i.e. not set as part of the application code).

I have create a test client for the application and I want the client to tell the application which file it should write to.

Can anyone tell me how I would go about this in Go?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: do you mean, like a flag or environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

If the location is not set, you'll need to read it in some way.

- You might want to read it from a command line flag passed in when running the command. The easiest way to do that is using the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package.
- You could read it from STDIN. The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-to-read-input-from-console-line) nicely explains how to do that.
- You could read it from an environment variable. Check out the [Environ function in the os package](https://golang.org/src/os/env.go?s=3349:3372#L105).

Comment: To add, you can also read it from the client as well. Just have the application expect it from a connection.