# equivalent of readline.get_line_buffer in golang

Tags: python, go

I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/n1nj4sec/pupy/blob/e40fecfb1dcc5812f433e212bee827a667cc8b81/pupy/pupylib/PupyCmd.py#L395) behaviour in my golang CLI based program.
The behaviour is simple, I just want to print something to console while user is typing something.

This is the code I have written.

```
// %a code that reads the user input in a different thread% 
fmt.Print("\r[*] this is a message.") // erases the current line then prints the message
fmt.Print("\n\r") // creates new empty line
fmt.Print(">>> " + %CURRENT_STDIN_LINE_BUFFER%) // prints the prompt ">>>" then writes the user input
```

The only missing thing is equilavent of readline.get_line_buffer() python function in golang.

Comment: [A possibly limited implementation of GNU Readline exists](https://github.com/chzyer/readline) if you just want to use that, or you can [try an alternative](https://github.com/peterh/liner) that provides some similar functionality.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895629/1135424

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from standard input in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-to-read-from-standard-input-in-the-console)