# How to detect key press event

Tags: go

My purpose is to print string sequentially and when the user enter some character, we pause the process and read stdin content. I know it's possible to catch os.Interrupt signal but I don't how to catch event in stdin.
I don't want to scan and wait user to enter text. The process is stopped when there is a keypress event.

My question: How detect event on stdin?

Here is current solution with your advice. Go routines not constitue an optimal solution because you can't manage them as threads. I currently continue working on this and keep you udpated.

```
func main() {
    quit := make(chan bool)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        fmt.Println("-----------------")
        fmt.Println("Go routine running :", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        go func() {
             select {
                case <-quit:
                return
             default:
                fmt.Println("Text received and changed")
                fmt.Println("-----------------")
                for {
                    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 1)
                    <-timer.C
                    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
                }
            }

            fmt.Println("Routine closed")
        }()

    }
    if scanner.Err() != nil {
        quit <- false
    }
}
```

Otherwise if I follow your solution @varius :

```
func main() {
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    for {
        timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 1)
        <-timer.C
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
if scanner.Err() != nil {
 /*handle error*/
}
}
```

But I can't change the scan content while program running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read input from console line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-to-read-input-from-console-line)

Comment: If you need to detect incomplete lines (aka chars or keypresses), you need a 3rd party lib like [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

Comment: @Vardius I don't want to read stdin and wait the user press "enter". I want to print text in while loop and pause the process when a user start to write some text

Comment: @BlancoVerde what is stoping you from using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28311177/2160958) ? Just implement a missing part, half job done already

Comment: I'm with @icza on this; to expand on his answer, on Unix-like systems, one should have the terminal's *line discipline* set to the so-called "raw" mode to have all keypressed be passed to the application ASAP and (almost) uninterpreted (read [this classic gem](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) for more info). Using appropriate terminal-abstraction library is a way to go here. On Windows, things are different but `termbox-go` abstracts them away presenting the same interface ascross all supported platforms; hence, recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if it will answer your question but **for those who want to determine a single keypress, without the `enter` key**, like below:

```
$ go run . <enter>
Key press => a
Key press => b
Key press => c
Key press => d
Key press => e
... (ctrl+c)
signal: interrupt
```

The module `github.com/mattn/go-tty` by [mattn](https://github.com/mattn/) might help.

- https://github.com/mattn/go-tty by mattn @ GitHub

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/mattn/go-tty"
)

func main() {
    tty, err := tty.Open()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer tty.Close()

    for {
        r, err := tty.ReadRune()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Key press => " + string(r))
    }
}
```

```golang
// go.mod
module sample/tty

go 1.16

require github.com/mattn/go-tty v0.0.3 // indirect
```

- Tested on:

  - Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz Dual-Core
  - macOS Catalina 10.15.7, Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), Alpine Linux v3.13