# How to capture the output of the terminal using Go?

Tags: go

I want to create a simple program using Go that can get an output in the terminal output. For example:

`echo "john" | goprogram`

The output is `hi john`

When using command `cat`

`cat list_name.txt | goprogram`

The output using

```
hi doe
hi james
hi chris
```

Is there a way to do this using Go?

Comment: Write a program that reads from stdin. You can use fmt.Scan functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read from standard input in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-can-i-read-from-standard-input-in-the-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read from [os.Stdin](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Stdin).  Here's an example implementation of the Hi program.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("hi", s.Text())
    }
    if s.Err() != nil {
        log.Fatal(s.Err())
    }
}
```

This program creates a [scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) to read os.Stdin by line.  For each line in stdin, the program prints "hi" and the line.