# How I can receive data for ever from TCP server

Tags: go, tcp, tcpclient

I try to create TCP client to receive data from TCP server,
but after server sending data only I receive data one even if server send many data, and I want to receive data forever, and I don't know what is my problem,and

Client:

```
func main() {
    tcpAddr := "localhost:3333"
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", tcpAddr, time.Second*7)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    // conn.Write([]byte("Hello World"))

    connBuf := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        bytes, err := connBuf.ReadBytes('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Rrecv Error:", err)
        }

        if len(bytes) > 0 {
            fmt.Println(string(bytes))
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    }
}
```

I'm following this [example](https://coderwall.com/p/wohavg/creating-a-simple-tcp-server-in-go) to create TCP test server

Server:

```
// Handles incoming requests.
func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    // Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    // Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
    _, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(buf)
    // Send a response back to person contacting us.
    var msg string
    fmt.Scanln(&msg)
    conn.Write([]byte(msg))
    // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: *" even if server send many data"* - your server does not send many data. There is only a single `conn.Write` immediately followed by a close of the connection.

Comment: you right but if I closed connection after Write no data will sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Read requires a Write on the other side of the connection

> want to receive data forever

Then you have to send data forever.  There's a `for` loop on the receiving end, but no looping on the sending end. The server writes its message once and closes the connection.

##### Server expects to get msg from client but client doesn't send it

> ```
>     // conn.Write([]byte("Hello World"))
> ```

That's supposed to provide the `msg` value to the server

> ```
>     _, err := conn.Read(buf)
> ```

So those two lines don't match.

##### Client expects a newline but server isn't sending one

`fmt.Scanln` expects to put each *whitespace separated* value into the corresponding argument.  It does not capture the whitespace.  So:

1. Only up to the first whitespace of what you type into server's stdin will be stored in `msg`
2. Newline will not be stored in `msg`.

But your client is doing

> ```
>         bytes, err := connBuf.ReadBytes('\n')
> ```

The `\n` never comes.  The client never gets done reading that first `msg`.

[`bufio.NewScanner` would be a better way to collect data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-can-i-read-from-standard-input-in-the-console), since you're likely to want to capture whitespace as well. Don't forget to append the newline to each line of text you send, because the client expects it!

##### Working code

I put these changes together into a [working example on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-MQMTWtHDFo).  To get it working in that context, I had to make a few other changes too.

- Running server and client in the same process
- Hard coded 3 clients so the program ended in limited amount of time
- Hard coded 10 receives in the client so program can end
- Hard coded 3 server connections handled so program can end
- Removed `fmt.Scanln` and have server just return the original message sent (because playground provides no stdin mechanism)

Should be enough to get you started.