# run `python.exe` to run the python shell interactively

Tags: python, shell, go

I am trying to run a exec.Command `python.exe` to run the python shell interactively. How can I type into it?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "io"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    
    fmt.Println("Before Python shell:")
    
    cmd := exec.Command("python.exe")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    _ = cmd.Run()
}
```

Comment: You can prompt for input from golang, then pass that along to `python -c "python expression"`, and have that be evaluated. Otherwise, call `python script.py`, but I don't think you'll get anything more than that

Comment: yes. is there a reference or reference link you can share. i would love to do that. that is workable for me. Probably a continues looped stdin and stdout

Comment: Maybe start here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715256/2308683

Comment: You don't have to marshal the input back and forth.  You just have to include `os.Stdin` when redirecting the input and output to python.

Comment: @erik258 thank you. i tried that and it failed with just a single stdin like this `cmd := exec.Command("python3");     cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin`. Maybe there was some issue since i am quite new to golang from python

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you put yours as the answer? I wish to mark it right. bufio worked for me. let me have a look at the api if i need to drill down. `scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin); for{fmt.Print("Enter Text: ");scanner.Scan();text := scanner.Text();if len(text) != 0 {`

Comment: "i tried that and it failed" there's a complete working example in my answer.  If you tried it and it didn't work for you, you made a mistake.  Or maybe it works different in windows where everything is a little wacky?

Comment: @erik258 the demo worked. but not for looped `stdin` and `stdout`. i am on windows and am expecting this to work with all linux, mac, and windows.

Answer (score 2):

If your `go` program's stdin and stdout is a terminal, and you set your `exec.Command`'s stdout *and stdin* to the `go` program's stdout and stdin, you can indeed expect `python` (in this case) to interact with the terminal just like it was executed directly.

This code:

```
package main
import(
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python3")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Has this behavior:

```
% go run t.go                                                                                                                                                                                       
Python 3.9.6 (default, Aug  5 2022, 15:21:02)
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello world")
hello world
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
>>> ^D
[2023/04/22 11:31:20 CDT ] ~
```

Your code was missing  `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin`.