# Printing a user inputed string n times in go

Tags: string, go

I'm new to go and I only wanted to print a user inputed string n times, but it just prints a whitespace n times instead. Here's my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var n int
    var s string
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
    }
}
```

any way to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What are you entering when you run the app? If I run it and type `10 foo` (then hit enter) it prints `foo` 10 times. If you want  `Scanf` to wait for enter to be pressed between the inputs then add `\n`.

Comment: @Brits Yes, I want it to do exactly that. But I have another question, what if I want to input a string that has spaces between the words. If I input `hi there` it will only outputs hi n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the [`Scanf` docs](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scanf)

> Scanf scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the format. It returns the number of items successfully scanned. If that is less than the number of arguments, err will report why. Newlines in the input must match newlines in the format. The one exception: the verb %c always scans the next rune in the input, even if it is a space (or tab etc.) or newline.

The two points most relevant to your question are:

- space-separated values
- Newlines in the input must match newlines in the format

So if you run your app, as is, and enter `20 foo` and hit enter you will get the expected output (`foo` printed 20 times). However, if you enter `20` then hit enter you will get 20 blank lines; to see why lets run:

```
var n int
var s string
fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)
_, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will panic with `panic: unexpected newline` because, as per the spec, "Newlines in the input must match newlines in the format". Assuming you wish to press enter after each input then you can use `fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &n)`. However, as you mention in the comments, if you use `fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &s)` and enter a string containing spaces then you will only get the first bit (because `scanf` uses spaces as delimiters).

If you want to get a whole line from `stdin` then the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20895552/11810946) provide some options e.g.

```
func main() {
    var n int
    var s string
    fmt.Println("How many times? ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &n)
    fmt.Println("What to output? ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    s, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s", s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the second `Scanf()` skipped, so for fix that simply you can just add new line character (/n) after your embedding variable.

like this

```
func main() {
    var n int
    var s string

    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &n)
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &s)
}
```