# Check if there is something to read on STDIN in Golang

Tags: go

I need a command line utility to behave different if some string is piped into its STDIN. Here's some minimal example:

```
package main // file test.go

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)

    if len(bytes) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Something on STDIN: " + string(bytes))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Nothing on STDIN")
    }
}
```

This works fine if you call it like that:

```
echo foo | go run test.go
```

If `test.go` is called without anything on STDIN, the thing stucks at...

```
bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
```

... waiting for `EOF`.

What do I need to do to get this going?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try wrapping stdin with a bufio.reader or something like that? or maybe using peek to see if there's anything to read?

Comment: read the doc: ReadAll goes on until there's an error or EOF, so ask yourself: was there an error reading from stdin? EOF? (you can send EOF in a terminal, it control-D on unix, something else on windows)

Comment: @loreb I read the docs. You describe the same stuff I did, there is nothing new mentioned.

Comment: @sontags uh? Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question then. It doesn't see EOF because, well, obviously the keyboard is still there, so you must either send an EOF from the keyboard (control-D in unix) or read the output one piece at a time, line by line or whatever.

Comment: @loreb Sorry, probably I was not clear enough: I am aware of the fact that there needs to be a EOF or an error in order to pass that ReadAll. And yes, CTRL+D sends a EOF, but thats not an option for usability reasons. So most likely ReadAll is the wrong approach, this is just to illustrate what the result should be. I basically ask for some hints how the expected behavior can be achieved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if Stdin has data with Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563616/determine-if-stdin-has-data-with-go)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I solved this by using os.ModeCharDevice:

```
stat, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()
if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("data is being piped to stdin")
} else {
    fmt.Println("stdin is from a terminal")
}
```

Comment: tested this, if you pipe stdin (ie. ./foo < /dev/null) from /dev/null you will think there is no stdin. That seems correct to me, since there is nothing to get from /dev/null anyways...

Comment: I like this solution better than @NickCraig-Wood because it uses standard go packages.

Comment: At least for me, this solution does not work under Git Bash on Windows, which is the default bash for Github Actions. This solution always prints "data is being piped to stdin" regardless of whether I run 'echo foo | go run .' or just 'go run .' without piping anything.  I do get good behavior for those two cases with this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74478987/11210494).

Answer (score 20):

Use the [IsTerminal](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal#IsTerminal) function from [code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh/terminal) (which was `exp/terminal`) or the [Isatty](https://github.com/andrew-d/go-termutil) function from [github.com/andrew-d/go-termutil](https://github.com/andrew-d/go-termutil)
 which is a much more focussed package.

If stdin is a terminal/tty then you aren't being piped stuff and you can do something different.

Here is an example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    termutil "github.com/andrew-d/go-termutil"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if termutil.Isatty(os.Stdin.Fd()) {
        fmt.Println("Nothing on STDIN")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Something on STDIN")
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
    }
}
```

Testing

```
$ ./isatty 
Nothing on STDIN
$ echo "hello" | ./isatty 
Something on STDIN
hello
$ (sleep 1 ; echo "hello") | ./isatty 
Something on STDIN
hello
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @sontags example provided!

Comment: FWIW, this did not work under Git Bash on Windows. (Neither andrew-d/go-termutil nor the golang.org terminal package worked properly in that case).

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above works for you, try this way:

```
stat, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("you have an error in stdin:%s", err)
}
if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeNamedPipe) == 0 {
    return nil, errors.New("you should pass smth to stdin")
}
```

It worked for me in both darwin (Mac OS) and linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: `$ go run sotest.go < sotest.go` results in `you should pass smth to stdin`.

The answer with `ModeCharDevice` behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
package main // file test.go

import (
    "bufio"
"fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    stats, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("file.Stat()", err)
    }

    if stats.Size() > 0 {
        in, _, err := in.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("reader.ReadLine()", err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Something on STDIN: " + string(in))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Nothing on STDIN")
    }
}
```

Thanks @Kluyg !

Comment: This doesn't work `( sleep 1 ; echo "hello" ) | ./test`, printing `Nothing on STDIN`.  I don't think you'll get this approach to work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here did not seem to work under Git Bash on Windows, which is the default bash for GitHub Actions on Windows. `isTerminal` from golang.org/x/term also did not seem to work.

For me, using https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty seems to work across platforms, including Git Bash / cygwin / MinGW on Windows.

Example usage ([playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/r396O-MzTue)):

```golang
func main() {
    if isatty.IsTerminal(os.Stdin.Fd()) || isatty.IsCygwinTerminal(os.Stdin.Fd()) {
        fmt.Println("stdin is terminal, nothing on os.Stdin")
        return
    }

    // stdin might or might not have data, but given it is not a terminal,
    // we should be able to read from it.
    //
    // Some examples:
    //    echo foo | go run .     # we can read "foo" from os.Stdin
    //    go run . < /dev/null    # we can read os.Stdin, but it is empty
    fmt.Println("stdin is not a terminal and we can read it")
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, os.Stdin)
}
```

Note that this is answering *"Can I read from os.Stdin (which might be zero length)?"*, and not *"Is there non-empty data in os.Stdin?"*. At least for my use case, the first form of the question is useful where "zero length data" is a type of input data that is OK to read.

I would be curious to hear if it does not work for someone else (including what platform).