# Reading length of piped input to Go command line program

Tags: go

I have the following code from [Determine if Stdin has data with Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563616/determine-if-stdin-has-data-with-go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file := os.Stdin
    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("file.Stat()", err)
    }
    size := fi.Size()
    if size > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%v bytes available in Stdin\n", size)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Stdin is empty")
    }
}
```

but no matter how I run it, size is always 0.

I am running Fedora 32 with Go version 1.14

Comment: how have you tried to run it?

Comment: A pipe doesn’t have a length. If you want to know the size you ha e to read it.

Comment: @FrankBryce echo 'test me' | go run test.go

Comment: @FrankBryce why did you remove your answer?! I upvoted it.

Comment: I didn't.. I wonder if a mod removed it for some reason

Comment: @DBWizz: It doesn't work in your case because there is no standard way to read the size of a named pipe (semantically a pipe has no size, implementations vary by buffer size). Even if you are on a system that returns a size for the pipe, it's only going to report up to the internal buffer size which doesn't tell you the size of the input.

Comment: @jimB I copied code from the web that others said worked for them.

Comment: @FrankBryce what is this operator <<< ?

Comment: @DBWizz: unfortunately not everything published on the internet is correct. `<<<` is a ["here string"](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html), and it does not necessarily create a pipe.

Answer (score -1):

You have to compile to code to get an executable.
Then you can pipe in any text to it, to get its size.

```
go build pipe.go
ls -lah pipe
2.1M Jul 23 23:06 pipe
```

Then you can run it by

```
echo "test" | ./pipe
5 bytes available in Stdin
```

Comment: Can you please share what you get when you run `go build pipe.go` and `echo "test" | ./pipe` ?

Comment: I get "0 bytes available in Stdin"