# how can I efficiently read numbers from stdin in Go (or why fmt.Scanf is so inefficient)

Tags: go

I started to do programming contests in go (just to learn the language) and to my surprise found that

```
var T int
fmt.Scanf("%d", &T)
```

is unimaginably slow. How slow? To [read 10^5 integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751429/reading-an-integer-from-standard-input-in-golang) it take me 2.5 seconds (in comparison python does it in 0.8 secs).

So why is it so slow and how should I properly read `int`, `uint64` and `float64`?

Comment: Do you use `bufio`? Why `fmt.Scanf` and not just `strconv.Atoi`? Post the code, there's not enough info.

Comment: @Ainar-G what code are you looking for. All I do reading a bunch of integers from stdin. And I clearly stated how I have done it (with `fmt.Scanf` which means that no, I have not used `bufio`). Why not just `strconv.Atoi` because I found how to read an integer in the answer on stackoverflow and it was telling to use scanf. I think it is more than enough info to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: @Salvador Dali Just curious, how you provide 10^5 integers to stdin? Can you do that at 2.5 seconds?

Comment: @Uvelichitel as I wrote, I am using Go to solve programming competitions. In all of them you receive input on `stdin` and have to write your answer in `stdout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only the integer as input, this should be faster (not tested though)

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func read() (int64, error) {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    // use strconv.ParseUint and strconv.ParseFloat in a similar way
    return strconv.ParseInt(string(b[:len(b)-1]), 10, 0)
}

func main() {
    i, err := read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    println(i)
}
```

run it like this

```
echo 123 | go run main.go
```

for interactive input, you might want to use bufio.NewReader, see [How to read input from console line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895552/how-to-read-input-from-console-line)

Comment: do you have any idea why scanf is so slow (it is kind of strange to have a function which does something super inefficient when there is an efficient approach to do something. P.S. thanks, I will try your answer

Comment: Well my code assumes that input is an integer. Scanf has multiple placeholders and is more flexible. This flexibility should come at a performance cost (more branches).

Comment: if you look at the source code http://golang.org/src/fmt/scan.go?s=3461:3523#L74, and go through the function calls, the critical inner function seems to be scanOne (line 930)  which has lots of case branches

Comment: @metakeule To see output why `Ctrl + D` has to be pressed ?