# Golang Read text file and take a slice from one of the read in values

Tags: algorithm, go

In my code below, I'm hoping to read a text file filled with a number 1-5 per line. I want it to scan the line and read one of values and see if its < 6 and perform an action. Unfortunately I'm unable to take a slice of the values, they only print as an array. Any advice on how i can fix my code please?

```
//This is the part of the program that will read from a text file named "file"
//To see what numbers were selected last time so the recipe for week two can be
//a completely new recipe group of 5
f, err := os.Open("file")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
for {
    var z int
    var n int
    n, err = fmt.Fscanln(f, &z)
    if n == 0 || err != nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("int z :", z)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked fine in my test.  Likely the file is formatted slightly differently or is in a different location?

```
for {
    var z int
    var n int
    n, err = fmt.Fscan(f, &z)
    if n == 0 || err != nil {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("int z :", z)
}
```

really, a variation of this question:
[Reading an integer from standard input in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751429/reading-an-integer-from-standard-input-in-golang)

Comment: sure the file says 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @Tbalz, you're using `fmt.Fscanln` which reads the whole line at a time, he's using `fmt.Fscan`.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense !